# save stream output as multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, stream, pipe

I have a program (`pull`) which downloads files and emits their contents (JSON) to stdout, the input of the program is the id of every document I want to download, like so:

```
pull one two three
>
> { ...one }
> {
    ...two
  }
> { ...three }
```

However, I now would like to pipe that output to a different file for each file it has emitted, ideally being able to reference the filename by the order of args initially used: `one two three`.

So, the outcome I am looking for, would something like the below.

```
pull one two three | > $1.json
>
> saved one.json
> saved two.json
> saved three.json
```

Is there any way to achieve this or something similar at all?

### Update

I just would like to clarify how the program works and why it may not be ideal looping through arguments and executing the program multiple times for each argument declared.

Whenever `pull` gets executed, it performs two operations:

1. **A**: Expensive operation *(timely to resolve)*: This retrieves all documents available in a database where we can lookup items by the argument names provided when invoking `pull`.
2. **B**: Operation specific to the provided argument: after **A** resolves, we will use its response in order to get the data needed for specifically retrieving the individual document.

This means that, having `A+B` called multiple times for every argument, wouldn't be ideal as `A` is an expensive operation.

So instead of having, `AB AB AB AB` I would like to have `ABBBB`.

Comment: Are you looking for `tee` command?

Comment: `for id in one two three; do pull "$id" > "$id.json"; done`

Comment: If it simply sticks the files and outputs them all together, then you'd have to write something to try to figure out where one ends and the next starts, how to name them, etc. Depending on the files' formats, this could be anywhere from tricky to impossible. I'd try to avoid sticking them all together in the first place, to avoid this mess.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm afraid executing the program multiple times wouldn't be ideal in this case. I have updated the question with additional details, in case that helps. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the hard way.

```
for f in one two three; do pull "$f" > "$f.json" & done
```

Unless something in the script is not compatible with multiple simultaneous copies, this will make the process faster as well. If it is, just change the `&` to `;`.

#### Update

Try just always writing the individual files. If you also need to be able to send them to stdout, just cat the file afterwards, or use `tee` when writing it.

If that's not ok, then you will need to clearly identify and parse the data blocks. For example, if the start of a section is THE ONLY place `{` appears as the *first* character on a line, that's a decent sentinel value. Split your output to files using that.

For example, throw this into another script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { ndx=1; split($0,fn); name=""; next; } /^{/ { name=fn[ndx++]; } { if (length(name)) print $0 > name".json"; }' <( echo "$@" ) <( pull "$@" )
```

call that script with `one two three` and it should do what you want.

#### Explanation

```
awk '...' <( echo "$@" ) <( pull "$@" )
```

This executes two commands and returns their outputs as "files", streams of input for `awk` to process. The first just puts the list of arguments provided on one line for `awk` to load into an array. The second executes your `pull` script with those args, which provides the streaming output you already get.

```
NR==FNR { ndx=1; split($0,fn); name=""; next; }
```

This tells `awk` to initialize a file-controlling index, read the single line from the echo command (the args) and split them into an array of filename bases desired, then skip the rest of processing for that record (it isn't "data", it's metadata, and we're done with it.) We initialize `name` to an empty string so that we can check for length - otherwise those leading blank lines end up in `.json`, which probably isn't what you want.

```
/^{/ { name=fn[ndx++]; }
```

This tells `awk` each time it sees `{` as the very first character on a line, set the output filename base to the current index (which we initialized at 1 above) and increment the index for the next time.

```
{ if (length(name)) print $0 > name".json"; }
```

This tells `awk` to print each line to a file named whatever the current index is pointing at, with ".json" appended. `if (length(name))` throws away the leading blank line(s) before the first block of JSON.

The result is that each new set will trigger a new filename from your given arguments.

That work for you?

#### In Use

```
$: ls *.json
ls: cannot access '*.json': No such file or directory

$: pull one two three # my script to simulate output

{ ...one... }
{
  ...two...
}
{ ...three... }

$: splitstream one two three # the above command in a file to receive args

$: grep . one* two* three* # now they exist
one.json:{ ...one... }
two.json:{
two.json:  ...two...
two.json:}
three.json:{ ...three... }
```

Comment: I just saw [M. Nejat Aydin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13809001/m-nejat-aydin)'s comment above, which was apparently there long before I posted my solution, lol

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I have updated the question with additional details. I believe that executing the program multiple times, might not be ideal in my use case. Thanks for your reply, though.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update you answer so thoroughly, Paul. So, as you mentioned, I believe the way to go here is really splitting the file after `pull` has finished as per your example. `awk` syntax feels a bit verbose but it does the job. :) I guess the only downside of this method is that it's blocking in a way it waits for `pull` to finish to only then, splitting output, but again, it gets the job done and helps me to keep the `ABBBB` process I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. You might consider rewriting your script to loop through the arguments after the initial work is done and write all the files at the same time if it takes very long, or just scheduling that part in a crontab if it doesn't have to be absolutely up to the minute. Then it could do that work every hour or six and write a file the next step could read in and scan for args to process... Either way, good luck. :)